# Send email to a certain person from a certain address with Gmail

Tags: gmail, smtp

I have both the default Gmail SMTP and my company's SMTP configured in Gmail.  My company has asked that I always send emails to them using their SMTP and from address.  But for general communication to other people I'd like to use my Gmail address.

Is there some way to auto mark certain `To:` addresses to use a certain `From:` or at least warn me?

Comment: Through the web interface I assume?  Are you using Firefox or Chrome? (a user script or greasemonkey script could do this for you)

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: That would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an explicit way of doing that, but it is a realy fantastic idea that you should sugest to the Gmail team.

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs&issue=116880&bucket=16937

I work in the same way with both emails is Outlook and you just need to get into the habit of checking the "From" address before you click send. Enabling the "Undo" lab goes a long way to rectifying mistakes.